# Bind the datatable with ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Data is not Displaying in the Combo Box

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Code");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Rows.Add("c1", "n1");
dt.Rows.Add("c2", "n2");
myCombo.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)dt).GetList();
myCombo.DisplayMemberPath = "Code";
myCombo.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
```

Answer (score 8):

instead of this line

```
myCombo.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)dt).GetList();
```

try to use this one

```
myCombo.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```